# Why does Valgrind think that this memory is "definitely lost"?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

Valgrind reports that Texture *tex is definitely lost. But I save this pointer in mtl->tex to free it later. Here is detailed message from valgrind:

> ==17191== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
>   ==17191==    at 0x4C2ABD0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>   ==17191==    by 0x4005FA: assignTex (test.c:30)
>   ==17191==    by 0x400689: main (test.c:47)

Here is the code(MCVE):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Tex {
    int a;
} Tex;

typedef struct MTL {
    char *textureFilename;
    struct Tex *tex;
} MTL;

void freeMtl(MTL *mtl) {
    if(!mtl) return;

    if(mtl->tex) free(mtl->tex);
    free(mtl);
}

void doStuff(Tex *tex) {
    tex->a = 5;
}

char err_is_error_set() {
    return 0;
}

void assignTex(MTL *mtl) {
    if(strlen(mtl->textureFilename) != 0) {
        Tex *tex = (Tex*)malloc(sizeof(Tex));
        memset(tex, 0, sizeof(Tex));

        doStuff(tex);
        if(err_is_error_set()) {
            return;
        }

        mtl->tex = tex;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MTL *mtl = (MTL*)malloc(sizeof(MTL));
    memset(mtl, 0, sizeof(MTL));
    mtl->textureFilename = "Test";

    assignTex(mtl);
    assignTex(mtl);

    freeMtl(mtl);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it definitely lost?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but if there is an error both `bmp` and `tex` become unreachable after being allocated.

Comment: I wrote MCVE but it was leak-free. In the process I solved my problem. Valgrind is smart - it checks that after program exits some pointers are not freed. In this case it was because tex was overriden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind gives "definitely lost" message if after program finished given pointer was not freed. In my case error was that later in code *tex* was assigned new value and previous value leaked(assignTex(mtl) called twice).

Answer (score 1):

For example if an error occured then there is a memory leak due to this code

```
    bmp_load_bitmap(bmp, mtl->textureFilename, 1/*flip vertically*/);
    if(err_is_error_set()) {
        return 0;
    }
```

bmp was not freed.

The same situation is also in this code snippet

```
    tex_create_texture(tex);
    if(err_is_error_set()) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Also it would be more safe to check whether the memory allocation was successfull.

Comment: Adding free inside if block gives the same message.

Comment: @pusheax You should insert free in any code path where it is required. Also check that a memory allocation was successfull.

Comment: @pusheax I do not know what is your result code but I pointed out that the code invalid and has bugs that result in memory leaks.